# Video stream over ethernet

Tags: tcp, udp, video-streaming, bandwidth, ethernet

I have several video servers connected to each other over 1Giga bit ethernet cable.
Video clips can be send from one server to another or live broadcasting.
What best protocol should I use (UDP, TCP...) to achive real time transfering of HD video frames?

Answer (score 0):

[RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) or a new combination like [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) over [ZeroMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroMQ).